# jquery remove/add select options after cloning select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to be able to clone a drop down list and filter only those options that were NOT yet selected in the group of select lists.

For example, having the following:

```
<select name="SelectService" class="selService">
<option value="1">Some service</option>
<option value="2">Another one</option>
<option value="3">One more</option>
</select>
```

When i click the "clone" button it would clone the select list with ONLY those options that have NOT been yet selected.

ex: select option "Some service" -> hit clone -> new select list is added with only option values: 2 and 3.

etc..cloning and removing select lists would re-fill the select lists based on options selected so far.

EDIT:
to better visualize it here is the screen shot:
[image]

SCENARIO:

1. i start off with only 1 drop down
   list (that has 5 options) =>
   1,2,3,4,5 -> first options is selected by default.
2. I hit clone ->
   new list is added with ONLY options
   2,3,4,5.
3. i select option 5 (in select list

   ## 2)
4. I hit clone -> new list (#3) is added
   with ONLY options 2,3,4
5. i select option 2 (in select list

   ## 3)
6. I hit clone -> new list (#4) is
   created with options 3,4

..and so on.

Now, When I remove Select list #2 (or any other select list) that means ALL select lists should re-fresh and include the selected option from deleted select list (in our case #2)

Help.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/SKVSu/1/

```
$('#clone').click(function() {
    var original = $('select.selService:eq(0)');
    var allSelects = $('select.selService');
    var clone = original.clone();

    $('option', clone).filter(function(i) {
        return allSelects.find('option:selected[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length;
    }).remove();

    $('#target').append(clone).append('<br />');
});
```

Comment: @Shane Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @Shane I have updated my answer to work with multiple selects. I'll let you try and work out a solution for the deletes though.