# cloning a select list which is dynamically created

Tags: jquery, grails, clone, gsp

My requirement is to clone the selectbox (where option are dynamic populated ).
I am trying to use the solution at - 
[jquery remove/add select options after cloning select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198175/jquery-remove-add-select-options-after-cloning-select-list)

My view codes is-

```
<tr> <td>Reference Table:</td>
<td><g:select name="tableCombo"
            noSelection="${['':message(code:'Select Table')]}"
            from="${result}" value="${tableName }" onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'getColumns', update:'columns', params:'\'tableCombo=\' + this.value')}"/> </td></tr>
<tr id ="cons"><td nowrap>Constraint On:</td>
        <td nowrap><g:select name="columns" from="[]" /></td>
        <td nowrap>Constraint Value:</td>
        <td nowrap><g:textField name="columnValue" value="${enterVal }" />                  
<a id="clone" >Clone</a>  ///how to call clone
```

I am new to jquery so Kindly suggest how to do it.
want to clone  cons  on click.

thanks.

Comment: can you make a fiddle out of your question, its hard to understand what problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: ?

```
$('#clone').click(function() {
   var consClone = $('#cons').clone();

   // now depends where you would like to put the copy 
   // of consClone to, for example, to the same table as the original #cons was:
   $('#cons').parent().append(consClone);   
});
```

Be warned though, it's better to have one id in an entire document, one quick way is to use class instead of id for cons

Comment: thanks Andreas. I need to get these cloned select box also on post back on the page with selected options in all the selects. is it possible using cloning or should i create the selects and copy only options?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean.. sorry. Could you elaborate more?