# Binding a asp.net dropdown list control with values getting fetched from database in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am getting the values to a dropdown list during the page_load event which fetches data from the database.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelectGrp" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSelectGrp_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

code in the page_load event:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      GetGroupDropDowndata();
    }

protected void GetGroupDropDowndata()
    {
        DataTable groupsData = lookupCache.AccessLookupData(Constants.GroupSelectionFilter.ToString());
        if (groupsData != null && groupsData.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            groupsData.DefaultView.Sort = "DropDownValue";
            groupsData = groupsData.DefaultView.ToTable();

            ddlSelectGrp.DataSource = groupsData;
            ddlSelectGrp.DataTextField = "DropDownValue";
            ddlSelectGrp.DataValueField = "DropDownBoxID";
            ddlSelectGrp.DataMember = "DropDownGroup";
            ddlSelectGrp.DataBind();
            ddlSelectGrp.Items.Insert(1, Constants.GroupAll.ToString());
            ddlSelectGrp.SelectedIndex = 1;
            btnGroupSave.Enabled = true;
            btnGroupSave.CssClass = "saveButton";
            //RadAutoGrpSelect.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I am copying the data from the first dropdown list to another one. I tested the same using some sample data with jquery and it worked for me.
Here is the code for that:

```
<html>
<head id="Head1">
<title>jQuery Clone Dropdown list with selected value</title>
```

```
<body>
<select name="SelectService" class="selService">
    <option value="1">Some service</option>
    <option value="2">Another one</option>
    <option value="3">One more</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btnclone" value="Clone Dropdown">
<div id="target">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnclone').click(function () {
        var original = $('select.selService:eq(0)');
        var allSelects = $('select.selService');
        var clone = original.clone();

        $('option', clone).filter(function (i) {
            return allSelects.find('option:selected[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length;
        }).remove();

        $('#target').append(clone).append('<br />');
    });
</script>
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve the same with the asp.net dropdownlist control with values getting fetched from db (in jQuery) ?
I mean how to bind the control in jquery with the values?

Comment: I assume that your `asp-dropdown` will be present at `page_load` with its options and once you have options the `asp.dropdown`  will be rendered in `html` as normal html `select`. Just get its `id` which is `ddlSelectGrp`  and replace it in place of `select.selService` i.e. `select.ddlSelectGrp` and everything should go smoothly!

Comment: Like you said, It is getting rendered as normal html select. Hence, I tried to  replace the `select.selService` with `select.ddlSelectGrp` but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: your above functionality of cloning what it does is it will store first ddl in `original` var and selects all the other `ddls` with class `selService` and stores in `allSelects` var. I am not sure what you want to achieve here? Can you elaborate bit so that it is easy to understand?

Comment: I just checked in the view source, the id `ddlSelectgrp` is coming up as `ctl00$ChangeGroupPopup$C$ddlSelectGrp` .if it's the reason, how can we fix it?

Comment: Regarding the functionalilty: Everytime i click the button, I am supposed to clone the exisiting dropdown list with values except for the one that is selected in the previous one. Here is the link: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198175/jquery-remove-add-select-options-after-cloning-select-list)

Comment: Is it hitting the js function? place a debugger and check?

Comment: Actually, I needed to add a class to the asp.net dropdownlist control, that would be select.ddlClone in here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was simple in the end.I added a class to the asp.net dropdownlist control and it worked for me.

Here is the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnClone').click(function () {<script type="text/javascript">$('#btnClone').click(function () {
var original = $('select.ddlClone(0)');
var allSelects = $('select.ddlClone');
var clone = original.clone();$('option', clone).filter(function (i) {
    return allSelects.find('option:selected[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length;
}).remove();
$('#target').append(clone).append('<br /><br /><br />');});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just checked in the view source, the id ddlSelectgrp is coming up as
>   ctl00$ChangeGroupPopup$C$ddlSelectGrp .if it's the reason, how can we
>   fix it?

[Comments:] you can use `<%=ddlSelectgrp.ClientID  %>` to get the rendered result of dropdownlist control's id.